# Replacing null values in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have array of objects like

```
{
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: null,
  key4: "value4",
  ...
}
```

How can I replace all null values to '-' string (maybe with es6 for shorter code)?

Comment: Wanna show some of those code examples so we can understand where you got to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can iterate over all keys of an object as follows:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b:2};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(someFunction);
```

Now, to replace `null`-values, you can just test for null and set it to '-'.

```
var obj = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: null,
  key4: "value4"
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if(obj[key] === null) {
        obj[key] = '-';
    }
})
```